# How to import javascript libraries using Parcel/Netlify?

Tags: javascript, importerror, netlify, parceljs

I'm building a vanilla js app and using CDN's works fine, but If I install an app like typed.js with npm, and then import it as `import typed from 'typed.js'` it works as it should on a local dev server.

However, once I push it and it's built on Netlify I get a console error stating:
`failed to resolve module specifier "typed.js". relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

I have tried changing the import in every way I can think of like `'typed'` , `'/typed'` , `'/typed.js'` , `'typed.js'` , `'typed.js/lib/typed.js'` , `typed.js/src/typed.js'` etc and using require instead of import.

Comment: Should be as simple as `import typed from "./typed.js"` using Import statement — if *typed.js* is **not** inside *node_modules*. Otherwise use: `import typed from "typed"`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: yeah, I figured...I get the same error with emailjs so I'm not sure where the disconnect is, It must be with Netlify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a very easy fix with Netlify, I needed to change the publish directory to "dist" within the build settings.